# How can I move my Sprite rightly in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript, 2d-games

I am a new in Unity, now I am making a simple 2D game, I create my player sprite as 32X32 pixels, but when I move the player from (0,0,0) to (0,32,0), It moves more than it's length. what can I make the sprite move just the length of it, by moving from(0,0,0) to (0,32,0)? Thanks very much.

I have used coco2d before, when I set the resolution of the game and the sprite, for example the game scene is 320x480, the sprite is 32x32, if i move the sprite for 32 pixels, it will exactly move 32 pixels. But in Unity it seems different.

Comment: show us your code or a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: maybe you can use [Rigidbody2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html). Add velocity to rigidbody. Also in project folder you have sprite in the editor you can see Pixels Per Unit 100. Try to can change it 32.

Comment: Unity uses it's own measurements system (I believe it's in metres?) - As a start, you may want to check out this forum thread: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/setting-up-unity-for-pixel-perfect-2d-project.268807/

Comment: It seems that I should get used to the unity's own measurements, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your game to be pixel-exact, then you need to change `pixel per units` of the sprite to 32(or whatever dimension your sprite has) if you haven't already. By default, this value is 100.

You can change the 'pixel per unit' value from the inspector menu / import settings. Simply select the sprite and edit the value.

Comment: It works, Thanks very much, But If I develop a 2d game by unity, Do I need to apply the pixel-exact or just get used to the units not the pixel?

Comment: Depends on what type of game you are making. If you want it to be a pixel exact game, yes you have to apply. If not, just work your way around. It is the developer's decision.